# How does one satisfy the installation requirement for pdb in Python 3 and using pip install -e?

Tags: python, pip, pdb

I was trying to install my project but I get this error:

```
pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///Users/pinocchio/predicting_generalization/automl
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /Users/pinocchio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from automl==0.1.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/pinocchio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from automl==0.1.0) (1.16.4)
Collecting pdb (from automl==0.1.0)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pdb (from automl==0.1.0) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pdb (from automl==0.1.0)
```

why is that happening? Why doesn't pip just install any version automatically?

Thi is the `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name='automl', #project name
    version='0.1.0',
    description='AutoML',
    #url
    author='Pinocchio',
    author_email='me9@school.edu',
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['torch','numpy','pdb','scikit-learn','scipy','matplotlib']
)

#install_requires=['numpy>=1.11.0']
```

---

I found:

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/issues/3397

but wasn't super helpful.

Comment: Where does the `automl==0.1.0` requirement come from?

Comment: oh let me paste the setup.py

Comment: Don't paste the entire file. Reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: `pdb` is not something you're supposed to install.

Comment: Why not user235?@user2357112

Comment: It comes with Python.

Comment: `pdb` is a built-in module.

Comment: (For the record, the downvotes are not mine)

Comment: I dont care, problem solved! :D

Answer (score 2):

pdb come with python. It's a built in module. No need to install it!